# Hidden field value in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do I get a hidden column's value in a GridView in asp.net?

Comment: You mean "how to get the value of a hidden field" or "how to hide some data in each row of a gridview so that on postback I can retrieve it"?

Comment: Please make your question more specific. In which event you need to access hidden field values?

Comment: Technically I overlooked a third option: how to hide some data in each row so that a client-side JS can retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly in a grid view you select the column and make it a template column like this:

```
<asp:Template Field Header Text="SavingId" Visible="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID = "lblSavingId" runat="server" Text ='<%#Bind(SavingId")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

after that on the coding side you can fetch the value easily like as:

```
string id= (gridview1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblSavingId") as label).text;
```

Answer (score 0):

If "view" is your GridView:

```
HiddenField test = view.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("myHiddenField") as HiddenField
```

Comment: The "hidden" column itself would be view.Rows[0].Cells[0]

Answer (score 0):

if your hidden filed in grid view itemtemplace then you can find in this way:

in item data bound event:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    // Find the hidden field   
    HiddenField _hdn =
    (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField Id Put Here"); 
}
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found that a column with Visible = False won't appear in the results.

What I had to do to get the desired behavior was set the column to visible, then hide it with a style set to "visibility: hidden; display:none;". When I do this, I can access the column's value by selecting the column/row as indicated by some of the other posts.

You can also do the same thing using a hidden field if you're using a DataList, but if you're in a GridView (from your post it sounds like this is what you're doing), you may need to take a similar approach.